# Creating new features from the data and time in a text variable

Tags: string, pandas, variables, split

I am working with a dataset that records the data and time in a single variable "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"   I want to separate it into two features:  "mm/dd/yyyy" and  "hh:dd"

I have tried a for loop to iterate through the all entries, split them based on the white space inbetween date and time and then assign them to new features.  I have had no success only generated a "settingwithcopy" warning and resulting in copying the entire string rather than the split up string into both new features.

```
`#defining the new features as sometimes an error is created saying 
there is no such variable as " ". 
ers_data["incident_date"] = ers_data["create_time_incident"]

ers_data["time_created"] = ers_data["create_time_incident"]
ers_data["arrival_time"] = ers_data["create_time_incident"]
ers_data["closed_time"] = ers_data["create_time_incident"]
ers_data["primary_dispatch_time"] = ers_data["create_time_incident"]

for i in range (ers_data.shape[0]):
  split_arrived = ers_data.arrival_time_primary_unit[i].split(" ")

#new feature for saving time of arrival
ers_data["arrival_time"][i] = split_arrived[1]


# attempting another way 
for e in ers_data.create_time_incident:
  ers_data["time_created"][e] = [e][-5:]`
```

from suggestions I have tried: 
    ers_data['incident_date'] = pd.to_datetime(ers_data['create_time_incident'], 
    format = '%mm/%dd/%YYYY %HH:%MM').dt.strfdate('%d/%m/%Y')

```
ers_data['time_created'] = pd.to_datetime(ers_data['create_time_incident'], 
format = '%mm/%dd/%YYYY %HH:%MM').dt.strftime('%HH:%MM')
```

resulting in:

```
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py in 
_convert_listlike_datetimes(arg, box, format, name, tz, unit, errors, 
infer_datetime_format, dayfirst, yearfirst, exact)
    259                 try:
    260                     result, timezones = array_strptime(
--> 261                         arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors)
    262                     if '%Z' in format or '%z' in format:
    263                         return _return_parsed_timezone_results(

pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data '6/18/2015 18:40' does not match format '%mm/%dd/%YYYY 
%HH:%MM' (match)
```

tried using dateutil.  It works to properly parse the text string in the variable. It is heavy on the computational time as it processes.

```
%%time
n = 0
for date in ers_data.create_time_incident:
    #print('Parsing: ' + date)
    dt = parse(date)
    ers_data["date created"]  =  dt.date()
    ers_data["incident_time"] =  dt.time()
    n +=1 
    if n%1000 == 0:
      print (n)
```

Comment: can you post some data & the expected output as values?

Comment: https://github.com/Glasiermedic/Emergency-Services-Posting-Model/blob/master/Cincinnati_Fire2015.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ti would be more efficient if you use the `pd.to_datetime()` on your data to get the values you want.
you can do something like below

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column_with_date_time_info'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column_with_date_time_info'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Time formatting info is available here http://strftime.org/

Comment: I will try that. Thanks for the doc link.

Comment: ers_data['incident_date'] = pd.to_datetime(ers_data['create_time_incident'], format = '%mm/%dd/%YYYY %HH:%MM').dt.strfdate('%d/%m/%Y')
ers_data['time_created'] = pd.to_datetime(ers_data['create_time_incident'], format = '%mm/%dd/%YYYY %HH:%MM').dt.strftime('%HH:%MM')

Comment: you have to tweak the format to match the data you have. in this case `%HH:%MM` had to be changed to `%H:%M`. i have updated the code in the answer as well. try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: OK so I did make that change and it worked way faster than my alternative.  Thank you. I had tried changing the date around thinking that was the issue but didn't even consider the time portion to be the real issue.